# Resources for quantum biology

Tags: resource-request, quantum-biology

Are there any books, courses, tutorials, etc. for studying quantum biology?
Preferably they provide some introduction/primer on the relevant quantum aspects of the quantum biological systems being described.

Comment: there was a review on nature physics a few years ago: https://www.nature.com/articles/nphys2474. I don't know how up to date it is though.

Comment: It might be good to try this on the Physics or Biology SE as well, since the most people here focus on quantum information

Comment: @glS While it looks like a good review, I would argue that a newer review would be preferred. At least for the field of quantum transport in photosynthesis, there have been many developments, especially in terms of debating the actual quantum effects (as far as I understand, I am no expert obviously)...

Comment: @JamesWootton I was not sure too, but I was told by Mithrandr24601 that it probably is fine to post it and see the reaction of the rest of the community. I will wait and if anyone has any complaints, I might move it...

Comment: a relatively recent paper that deals with quantum biology is https://arxiv.org/abs/1710.07466 (published on June of this year on [nature comm](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41467-018-03312-x), so it should be updated). You might find the references in there useful

Answer (score 2):

Following are some of the latest resources on Quantum Biology

Youtube video by the Royal Institution: [*Quantum Biology: An Introduction*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bLeEsYDlXJk)

Wikipedia page on [quantum biology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_biology) (and links therein)

University of Illinois at Urbana-Champaign, NIH Center for Macromolecular Modeling & Bioinformatics, [quantum biology research page](https://www.ks.uiuc.edu/Research/quantum_biology/)

TED Talk by Jim Al-Khalili: [*How quantum biology might explain life’s biggest questions*](https://www.ted.com/talks/jim_al_khalili_how_quantum_biology_might_explain_life_s_biggest_questions)

Comment: Welcome to Quantum Computing SE! As Revolvy has copied the Wikipedia page of the same name, I've replaced the link with the Wiki one as this is better practise. It would also be helpful if you could give a brief explanation of what the links are about, as this is a useful thing for an answer to a resource request to do

Comment: This is not really what I am looking for... i was more interested in a more technical introduction (the actual quantum mechanics behind these phenomenon), rather than a popular science description of quantum biology to laymen.